# Video re-streaming server (video output format)

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, video-capture, mjpeg

I need to develop a video streaming server which would stream a live video to multiple users. It needs to support the following "video" sources for the re-stream server:

- web-camera
- surveillance camera (already supports MJPG stream)
- scanner

I understand that I would need a different driver for adding support to each video input device.

I also need to support the video-display in:

- web-browsers

  - Mozilla Firefox 3.6
  - Internet Explorer 8
- desktop applications developed in C++ / QT 4.6

My questions:

1. What would be a good video output format that can be used to support the required browsers/applications?
2. Is there a similar Open-Source, Commercial, etc. solution which I could use to make my work easier and faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to complete the video re-streaming server and I've used the following:

1. [MJPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) format for video stream, as it is basically a standard which is natively supported in modern browsers, except in IE, but there are free ActiveX controls, allowing IE to properly display MJPG streams.
2. Solutions, libraries:

   - For the Web Camera I've used the [TVideoGrabber](http://www.datastead.com/products/tvideograbber.html) from Datastead Software, it is a commercial solution, but it works great, and it can be used with a lot of environments (Visual Studio, Delphi, C++Builder).
   - For the Scanner, I used [WIA 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29) library.
   - Security Camera already supported MJPG, so I basically forwarded the stream from the camera as my server's output.

Comment: Somewhat offtopic, but could you please tell me an example of a free ActiveX control that allows IE to display MJPGs? I'm struggling with IE compatibility

Comment: @Rick: I've been very satisfied with the Axis Media Control Activex, but, I've stumbled on a couple of others, amongs them I remember MxPEG ActiveX. By the way, you should ask a question, so you might get a better answer...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no good consensus on one format for streaming.  I would investigate multi-stream (http streaming, RTP streaming, etc) solutions so you can support multiple clients (Firefox, IE, iOS Safari, Android, etc).

A couple of good streaming servers products are:

- [Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/) (open source and commercial)
- [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) (commercial w/ free trial)

There are tons of other good options out there too.